# Cannot import pyscipopt into python (ubuntu)

Tags: python, scip

I am trying to use scip's python interface. I have already downloaded the python interface and installed it according to the instructions given in 
Python interface for the SCIP Optimization Suite. However, when I try to import pyscipopt to python, there is an ImportError:No module named 'pyscipopt.scip'.
I'm using scipsuite-3.2.1 under ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to be in a different directory than from where you installed the interface. Python gets confused when trying to import something when there is a directory of the same name in the current directory. Please go into the subdirectory `scip/interfaces/python/tests` and try running the provided test files.